# Does anyone know what this error is related to? I have checked my syntax, my declarations, most of everything, but can't find the solution

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, VERY new. I am reading a C++ book and doing beginner level problems on the side to get a practical grasp. But there seems to be a very specific issue here.

With my VERY limited understanding, i have tried to check and recheck things but for some reason, i can't get rid of this error in line 16.

This is no homework or assignment, i am learning C++ just to add to my resume.

Any and all help + tips will be highly appreciated.
[Here is the image associated with the problem showing the code and error statement at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RodQU.png)

Comment: Please copy&paste both the code and the error into the question.

Comment: Please refer to the [help] to learn how to ask a good question. In particular, be sure to add a [mcve] in the post *itself*.

Comment: Next time, paste the code and error in to the question body itself. Links (and images) can go stale. Also, images of code aren't convenient.

Comment: And by the way, the compiler tells exactly **the line and the column** where it detect the error. Thus, you just have to verify carefully the code around that point.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to add ">" before the ";".
Remove the ">" and recompile.

Comment: LOL. Actually, when i posted the question, i went to take a look again and i saw that damned ">"....  and i was like ... da hell is that? :D

But still, Thank for your prompt reply. Looking forward to answering some questions myself one day...